# If I keep iv paramater secret, does it still need to be random in AES/CBC?

Tags: cryptography, aes, initialization-vector

Does it make a problem about security as long as key and iv kept secret but same?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I did some research and learned why iv used. As mentioned in the answer below it's a protection way against frequency attacks. And there is two requirements when creating iv: uniqueness and unpredictability.

The algorithm that I thought for creating aes key and iv is:
Get two values from a certain elliptic curve point that agreed before by using asymetric encryption.(x,y)

```
Aes.Key <- HASH(x)
(string)unique <- timestamp()
(string)unpre <- y
Aes.IV <- HASH(unique + unpre)
```

And share data as {encryptedmessage, timestamp}

Is this logic alright?

Comment: It depends on how you're applying the asymmetric cipher. If you're using a KEM approach where the you're generating a new elliptic curve point for each encryption, then this seems fine, but if your point (x,y) is a long-term secret, then this still lacks randomization and LDMJoe's answer applies. Either way...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. It is much better suited for [crypto.se]. It should be clarified how the protocol looks and how often the elliptic curve point change.

Answer (score -1):

You need a random (or at least pseudo-random) Initialization Vector for block ciphers like AES.

Ripped straight from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector):

> Randomization is crucial for encryption schemes to achieve semantic
>   security, a property whereby repeated usage of the scheme under the
>   same key does not allow an attacker to infer relationships between
>   segments of the encrypted message.

Comment: Yes, it says. But I think this requirement for scenarious that iv sent with message publicly. key, iv, plaintext all of them secret, This is a different situation. Am I wrong?